# Changing emails across all sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using `MailApp.sendEmail` and I have over 100 sheets that has a set of email recipients. Some of the sheets have the same set of recipients. Is there any way that I can edit the email list whereby if I remove an email in Spreadsheet1, it gets removes on all the other spreadsheet too?

This hit me hard when I realized that I need to change over 100 sheets to remove/add emails which takes a lot of time and is not productive.

Comment: You can use [`.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) to loop through all of the sheets in your spreadsheet and update the values. Long term, I'd consider ways to make this easier to maintain, though.

Comment: My sheets are separated. Within a spreadsheet, I only have 1 sheet. An example would be, in Machine 1 folder, I have 10 machines which equates to 10 different spreadsheet which are not interconnected within a spreadsheet itself.

Comment: @D3FTY How are the emails organized in the Sheet? Are they all in separate rows? What would the triggered action do - remove the row that contains the email?

Comment: Its in a variable. ``var receipients = "email1,email2,email3,email4"``I am assigning the email via the script itself. However, if there is  way to manipulate and remove/add through the spreadsheet itself, I will proceed on to have it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace strings on all sheets in all Spreadsheets**

My function was contained in a spreadsheet since it needed a ui for the dialog to run in.  I choose two other spreadsheets whose ids I put in the ssA array and I also included my container spreadsheet id.  It runs very fast and it matches the entire cell so if you want to replace substring then change `.matchEntireCell()` to false.

```
function replaceStringOnAllSheetsInAllSpreadsheets() {
  var ssA=["SpreadsheetId","SpreadsheetId",...];
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var resp=ui.prompt("String/Replacement", "Enter string/replacement", ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var rA=resp.getResponseText().split('/');
  ssA.forEach(function(id){
    var spsh=SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    try{spsh.createTextFinder(rA[0]).matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith(rA[1]).findAll();}
    catch(e){}
  });
}
```

This version runs off of a spreadsheet list:

```
function replaceStringOnAllSheetsInAllSpreadsheets() {
  var ssA=["ssid","ssid",...];//add spreadsheet ids
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('ChangeList');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);//using first two columns for search string and replacement
  var vA=rg.getValues();//first column is search string and second column is replacement
  vA.forEach(function(rA){
    ssA.forEach(function(id){
      var spsh=SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
      try{spsh.createTextFinder(rA[0]).matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith(rA[1]).findAll();}
      catch(e){}
    });
  });
}
```

It would probably be easier to put this last version in it's own container spreadsheet so you can maintain your replacement list.

[Spreadsheet Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createTextFinder(String))

Comment: I assume this only applies if my sheets are within 1 spreadsheet right? As mentioned, my sheets are separated. Within a spreadsheet, I only have 1 sheet. An example would be, in Machine 1 folder, I have 10 machines which equates to 10 different spreadsheet which are not interconnected within a spreadsheet itself.

Comment: I still have to go through each spreadsheet manually in this case since the sheets are unique to its own spreadsheet.

Comment: Try it again I added the code to go through an array of spreadsheet ids.

Comment: I tried the second code of yours. I had 3 SS ids however when I ran the function, it change only applied to the spreadsheet that has a script containing this function. The other 2 spreadsheet's text did not change. Your variable ``sh``, you are assigning the sheetname that contains this function right?

Comment: Managed to make it work. Yes I did make individual container for this function. Thanks alot, this helps me cut own a lot of times in replacing / adding emails.